# 404 when receiving a slack modal submission with nodeJS and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, slack-api

I'm having trouble receiving the content of a Slack modal submission using nodeJS and express.

Here is my slack view that I can successfully open via an interactive compoennt

```
{
  view: {
    'type': 'modal',
    'title': {
      'type': 'plain_text',
      'text': 'Example Modal '
    },
    'close': {
      'type': 'plain_text',
      'text': 'Cancel'
    },
    'callback_id': CALLBACK_IDS.MY_CALLBACK,
    'blocks': [
      {
        'type': 'input',
        'block_id': 'input_id_1',
        'label': {
          'type': 'plain_text',
          'text': 'Example'
        },
        'element': {
          'type': 'plain_text_input',
          'action_id': 'input_id_1',
          'placeholder': {
            'type': 'plain_text',
            'text': 'PLACEHOLDER'
          },
          'multiline': false
        },
        'optional': false
      },
    ],
    'submit': {
      'type': 'plain_text',
      'text': 'Save',
    },
  },
};
```

When the user submits the view, I receive a payload

```
{
          "type" => "view_submission",
          "team" => {...
    },
          "user" => {...
    },
    "api_app_id" => "XXX",
         "token" => "XXX",
    "trigger_id" => "XXXX",
          "view" => {
                      "id" => "XXX",
                 "team_id" => "XXX",
                    "type" => "modal",
                   "title" => {
             "type" => "plain_text",
             "text" => "Example Modal :rocket:",
            "emoji" => true
        },
                   "close" => {...},
                  "submit" => {...},
                  "blocks" => [...],
        "private_metadata" => "",
             "callback_id" => "my_callback_name",
                   "state" => {
            "values" => {...},
                    "hash" => "XXX",
          "clear_on_close" => false,
         "notify_on_close" => false,
            "root_view_id" => "XXX",
        "previous_view_id" => nil,
                  "app_id" => "XXX",
             "external_id" => "",
                  "bot_id" => "XXX"
    }
}
```

I cannot find a way to intercept this message using the node slack library and the createMessageAdapter from `@slack/interactive-messages`

I have tried the following

```
const slackInteractions = createMessageAdapter(process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET);
slackInteractions
    .action({ view: { callbackId: CALLBACK_IDS.MY_CALLBACK }}, myCallback)
    .action({ type: 'view_submission' }, myCallback)
```

But everytime my express app returns a `404 Not Found`

What's the correct way to intercept slack modal submission ?

I have been taking inspiration from [this page](https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/interactive-messages) along with various other sources from the slack API documentation

Comment: `view_submission` is not yet supported for `@slack/interactive-messages` (https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-sdk/issues/883). it's supported in the Bolt framework though (https://slack.dev/bolt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working. In short:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const {createEventAdapter, errorCodes} = require('@slack/events-api');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const slackInteractions = createMessageAdapter(process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET);
const app = express();

slackInteractions.viewSubmission(CALLBACK_IDS.MY_CALLBACK, async (payload, respond) => {
  return ''; //or some view update code
});

// all slack interactions here, before the body parser

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    verify: (req, res, buf) => {
        req.rawBody = buf
    }
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
    extended: true
}));

// all post or get urls here, after the body parser declaration

const port = process.env.APP_SLACK_PORT || 3000;

http.createServer(app).listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Returning an empty string will close the window. If you need to update the view after the form submission, you can return the updated view inside the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of providing the answer I actually ended up using, we switched to using the Bolt framework which is more suited to building Slack applicatiins faster, and is more up to date with the actual Slack SDK.

The only thing needed to register a view submission in Bolt

```js
app.view(YOUR_CALLBACK_ID, viewSubmissionHandler);
```